# Could not get resource for Android Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components

I applied to my project Android Architecture Components, by adding this lines to build.gradle:

```
// Android Architecture Lifecycle
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"

// Android Architecture Room
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

It worked, but after updating Android Studio to Canary 3 version I'm still getting this error while compiling

> Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get
>   resource
>   'https://jitpack.io/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0-alpha1/runtime-1.0.0-alpha1.pom'.
>
> Error:org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not HEAD
>   'https://jitpack.io/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0-alpha1/runtime-1.0.0-alpha1.pom'.
>   Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

... other poms from library with the same error.

I tried restarting Android Studio, uninstalling app and of course clean-rebuild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the new public Maven repo that Google is using to your `build.gradle` file.

For example, you could add it to the `allprojects` closure in the top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Then, all of your modules (e.g., `app/`) will know to look there in addition to other places for the artifacts.

From your error message, it would appear that Android Studio is only looking in `jitpack.io`.

Comment: Don't know why but I wasn't using jitpack.io so after removing this line, everything works. Also I had such configuration like you mentioned but with additional line.